# Need a Java reg Ex to read numbers in a string

Tags: java, regex

I've got a number of different string that look something like:

- 1
- 1,2
- 1 2
- 1 and 2
- 1, 2 and 3
- 1, 93

So thats:
- single numbers (potentially multiple digits)
- sequences seperated by 'and', commas or spaces

I'd like to write a Reg Ex to pull back just the numeric bits of the string. I had thought something like this would work:

```
Pattern.compile("^(?:(\\d+)[^\\d]+)*$");
```

The idea being that it should match and capture sequences of digits, skip multiple non-digits characters and repeat

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with [`\d+`](http://regexr.com?31t46)?

Comment: from this string: "13, 23 and 33" you want to extract this list of numbers: [13, 23, 33] or you want to extract a single number: 132333?

Comment: I'd like to extract all three numbers: 13, 23 and 33. I'm happy to keep calling the matcher for each matched number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you not just doing a match on digits here?:

```
    String str = "1, 2 and 3, 93";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }
```

Comment: That's the one. I was making the the Reg Ex far too complex. Thanks everybody

Comment: BTW, Is there any way of knowing before I start looping many matches where will be? I was planning on using matcher.groupCount() to get it to tell me how many elements will match and creating an array to hold the results. This would require the more comples regEx though  :-/

Comment: If you want to avoid more complex regex expressions for your array, you could dump all matches into an ArrayList & convert after.

Comment: That's probably the easiest solution. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

why not match on "\d+"?

```
public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "13, 23 and 33";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        Matcher m =  p.matcher(s);
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (m.find()) {
            result.add(new Integer(m.group()));
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

prints out

```
[13, 23, 33]
```